# I have to attach two event (click and sortable) on one element

Tags: mootools, mootools-sortable

here is the problem,I have to attach two event (click and sortable) on one element,but when i click the element,it also trigger sortable complete event. Is there any way to solve this?
I saw the source code of sortables,it bind mousedown event,so it will trigger by click.while how can i deteted whether is fired by click or drag.

otherwise,if there is a good way to detect element resort or not will be fine.

Comment: What is the funcionality you want with the click?

Comment: can you explain a bit better, maybe you can check if the mouseup is in the same spot? ie no mouse movement?

Comment: what i am doing,it's design a web file manager.so click is into the folder,drag is to sort folder.   is mouseup can tell me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, pointed out by Timmeh at the #mootools irc, is to use the `onSort` event and have a flag there.

Like:

```
onSort: function () {
    this.sorted = true;
},
onComplete: function (el) {
    if (this.sorted) {
        alert("complete trigger complete");
    }
    this.sorted = false;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/F2VKK/4/)

Comment: sorry,I don't realy understand the `cancel` event.and what i used is sortables.https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Drag/Sortables.js

Comment: @nay, I had used a drag.drop example, I updated the fiddle with a sortables example. Check here - __http://fiddle.jshell.net/hLJ8c/__

Comment: did I forget to say the `complete` event?when click element,`complete` and `click` event will both fire.I don't want fire `complete` event when click.http://fiddle.jshell.net/hLJ8c/2/

Comment: wondeful!that works fine.but I found another bug,with mootools compat,a little move will trigger click,you can try it,but it dosen't matter,I usually use nocompat. btw,I want detect whether is reSort,http://fiddle.jshell.net/hLJ8c/3/ here is my solution,can you find a better way? and thanks for help!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "detect whether is reSort"? interesting bug with nocompat...

Comment: I drag and hold the element #1 through other element,then go back to element #1's begin place and drop.now the list's sort is still like it was borne.not change any more.but the `complete` event still fired.So I want to know when sortables complete, is there a better way to detect the list is reSort or not

Comment: @nay, check this: **http://fiddle.jshell.net/F2VKK/5/** - I added a new function to compare arrays and by that use the flag. The problem with compat/more is that it uses the snap, you can re-define it in options and add a bigger value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the element seems to work http://fiddle.jshell.net/F2VKK/3/

Comment: here is a bug,when I drag element one,alert "drag",then I click element one,it still alert "drag".but other element  will alert "click"